# multivariable scalar integer injections

Tags: calculus, functions, integers

I’m looking for multivariable scalar integer injections, mainly of $2$ and $3$ variables (points), that have possibly the smallest results.

Is there a universal method to find those functions with N variables?

(looking for a way to efficiently store $\text{2D}$ and $\text{3D}$ points in some kind of hashset)

Comment: So injective functions over an integer lattice in 2/3 dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean by 'smallest result'? The term 'smallest result' implies a partial order on the codomain of the functions, with a least element, which I'm not sure if the latter exists if the codomain is the integers or an integer lattice.

Comment: It seems to be injective functions from an integer lattice to the integers.

Comment: In general, the cardinality of the class of functions from a countably infinite domain (an integer lattice here) to a countably infinite codomain (the integers) is the cardinality of the reals, so depending on what you mean with your question, this problem may not even be decidable.

Comment: If you are looking for efficient hash algorithms, it may be better to ask this question on the Theoretical Computer Science Stackexchange instead of here.